# How to generate a histogram in Django view (from Pandas DF) and pass to template?

Tags: python, django, dataframe, plot

I have a script that gets executed when the following view function is called in Django:

```
def CalScriptResultsView(request):
    all_activities = models.CalEvents.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    activities = ['Undefined',]
    for activity in all_activities:
        activities.append(activity.activity_code)

    script_result = gCalScriptMain.main(activities)

    return render(request, 'gCalData/gCalData_result.html', {'script_result': script_result})
```

The script `gCalScriptMain.main()` reads events in a Google calendar and builds a Pandas data frame. The headers (columns) of the data frame are the activities defined by the user and the index (rows) is made of date type dates (e.g. 2017-10-02). The actual data consists in number of hours spent on each activity for each day (in a three month period).

I want to be able to plot a histogram that looks something like this:
[image: Desired histogram type]

And I have to somehow return the histogram to the view so that then it gets passed to the corresponding template and can be displayed on the webpage.

What I have tried is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.hist()
plt.savefig('path/to/hist.png')
```

But it just generates a blank file.

However, I'm also doubting if this is a good approach or if there is something better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found pygal to be a good tool for what I want to accomplish. I'm creating an .svg file and calling it from the template.

```
line_chart = pygal.Line()
line_chart.title = 'Hours spent in each activity during the specified 
period ({} to {})'.format(input_start,input_end)
line_chart.x_labels = map(lambda d: d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
list(df.index.values))
for activity in act_hours:
    line_chart.add(activity, df[activity])

static_path = 'images/charts/line_chart_{}.svg'.format(user.id)
line_chart.render_to_file('static/' + static_path)

activities['static_path'] = static_path
```

In the template:

```
  <div class="container">
    {% with chart_path=script_result.static_path %}
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="{% static chart_path %}">
      Error: Your browser doesn't support SVG files
    </object>
    {% endwith %}
  </div>
```